# Unreal Engine: Access Violation on FObjectFinder

Tags: c++, unreal-4, particles

I got a problem with my project in unreal. I wrote some code about a month ago and it worked fine until yesterday when the editor started crashin on launch. I get this error message in the log:

```
[2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: Fatal error!
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x000008d0
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000002548206A UE4Editor-Landscape.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000000B927D45 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000000B95BF0E UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000145DE8FD UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000001469DABC UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146B5259 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146B4774 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146CB0C3 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146D5A3A UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146D51B2 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000F7A72E21 UE4Editor-Lyfe_Game.dll!ConstructorHelpersInternal::FindOrLoadObject<UParticleSystem>() [c:\program files\epic games\ue_4.18\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\public\uobject\constructorhelpers.h:35]
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000F7A7314F UE4Editor-Lyfe_Game.dll!UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell::UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell() [c:\users\megapoort\desktop\lyfe\lyfe_game\source\lyfe_game\private\compound_particlecomponent_cell.cpp:30]
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000144605CD UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x0000000014698696 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000145E3EC4 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000F7A6B41D UE4Editor-Lyfe_Game.dll!ACompoundCloud_Cell::ACompoundCloud_Cell() [c:\users\megapoort\desktop\lyfe\lyfe_game\source\lyfe_game\private\compoundcloud_cell.cpp:64]
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000144605CD UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146D91B0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146BB41F UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x0000000014462547 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000149CE6C0 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x0000000014C22282 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000004489F60D UE4Editor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000004489F91E UE4Editor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66F7F71 UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66FC4EC UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66F525A UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66F54AA UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B6702379 UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B6703D57 UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000005ED03034 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000005F271431 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000005F271431 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:750][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:751][  0]LogWindows: FPlatformMisc::RequestExit(1)
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:751][  0]Log file closed, 06/25/18 22:39:29
```

`compoundcloud_cell.cpp:64` is where I create a default subobject for the actor. In its constructor (`compound_particlecomponent_cell.cpp:30`) The code that crashes the editor is located. The line that is logged here is:

```
auto psAsset = ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UParticleSystem>(TEXT("ParticleSystem'/Game/ParticleSystems/PS_CompoundCloud_SingleCelled.PS_CompoundCloud_SingleCelled'"));
```

The code snippet where I create the component looks like this:

```
std::string center = "CenterSystem";
    UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell* temp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell>(center.c_str());
    particles.Add(temp);
    RootComponent = temp;
```

By now I tried loading different particle systems and in differen classes and I always get access violations. I'm not entirely sure anymore it's my mistake. Could this be a bug within the engine?

It would be fantastic if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Still no answer to this problem. Still no solution. If anyone wants to have a look: https://github.com/GameAboutThings/Lyfe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it was nothing to do with the FObject finder or the particle system itself.
There were some unconnected nodes in the material used in the particle system.
Check your materials!